# linq count by 2 conditions

Tags: c#, linq

I have one table like this.

```
Age Group

20  G1
21  G2
20  G2
21  G1
22  G3
21  G1
20  G2
21  G2
22  G3
20  G1
22  G3
```

The result I want is

```
Age Grp Count

20  G1 2 
20  G2 2
21  G1 2
22  G2 2
22  G3 3
```

I can't figure it out how to calculate by 2 group by

I have only 1 group by

```
   var thirdResultQuery=from row in secondResultQuery
                         group row by new {row.Grp  } into g
                         select new
                         {

                             g.Key.Grp,
                             ageCount = g.Count()
                         };
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `Age` in the `GROUP`

```
var thirdResultQuery    =   from row in secondResultQuery
                            group row by new {row.Grp, row.Age} into g
                            select new
                            {
                                g.Key.Age,
                                g.Key.Grp,
                                ageCount = g.Count()
                            };
```

Comment: oh yea.. that was my previous query. why did i think that is not working?? thanks man..

Comment: @william what is your previous query?

Comment: @ JW, can you answer this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351780/combining-two-datatable-and-getting-the-amount-from-second-table-by-using-linq

Comment: exactly like ur answer. but when i was calculating the answer, it seemed like i didn't get the correct count. i must have miscalculated..